# Detecting idle time in .NET CompactFramework Applications

Tags: c#, compact-framework

We want to activate a process if the user does not interact for 2 mins with our compact framework application running on our custom built devices.

I found an excellent C# sample code of Code Project(http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ApplicationIdle.aspx) but it is not supported for compact framework as this code depends on Timers Class and Application.Idle events.

Can someone suggest me how to detect idle time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This blog entry](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/05/19/DetectingApplicationIdle.aspx) is exactly what you need.

(Archived version: http://web.archive.org/web/20090615073146/http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/05/19/DetectingApplicationIdle.aspx)

Comment: Not able to use this APIs on Windows XP box:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471794/unable-to-load-dll-coredll-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-on-wi

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the .NET Compact Framework in nearly 4 years, but maybe this is something that you could P/Invoke?  Or maybe OpenNetCF have something for this in their library? (that one saved me a couple of times back in the days.)  I just did a quick search over there and they do have a class for Timers, you might want to check it out and see if it can help: http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/

Answer (score 0):

[Differences Between the .NET Compact Framework and the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2weec7k5.aspx):

> **Timers**  The Start and Stop methods for a `System.Timers.Timer` object are
>   not supported, but you can start and
>   stop timing by setting the Enabled
>   property of a
>   `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` object to
>   true or false.

You can also use [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

**Supported in:** 3.5, 2.0, 1.0 .NET Compact Framework

You can use a Timer to detect idle activity like so: every time the user interacts with the application, reset a timer (that has an interval of say 5 minutes). If the Timer fires, then the application has been idle for 5 minutes.

Comment: But there is no support for System.Windows.Forms.Application.Idle event in compact framework. That's where I'm struck now.

Comment: So he should put a timer reset in the Click for every Form and
Control in the app?  Seriously?  How would that ever be maintainable?

Comment: Hi Chris: that's not what I was suggesting. I done it before, by creating a base form containing the idle logic, and then inheriting from it.

Comment: ...which seems equivalent to the example you linked to.